# Changes in logging since version 2.5

Tags: python, logging

I have been using the python logging module for quite some time now, but recently, when testing compatibility with older python versions I ran into some trouble:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hunter.py", line 16, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/config.py", line 85, in fileConfig
    _install_loggers(cp, handlers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/logging/config.py", line 229, in _install_loggers
    logger.addHandler(handlers[string.strip(hand)])
KeyError: 'hunterFileHandler'
```

with the following config file (important parts only):

```
[loggers]
keys=root,hunter

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler, hunterFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_hunter]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, hunterFileHandler
qualname=hunter
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_hunterFileHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("logs/hunter.log", "a", 0, 10,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s:[%(name)s][%(levelname)5s] %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Is there a simple way to make the configuration backward compatible without duplicating most of it?

Comment: Looks like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1018527/183066) might be useful to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely caused by the space in this line:

```
keys=consoleHandler, hunterFileHandler
                    ^
```

Due to a bug in 2.5, the leading space is not skipped, and you get a `KeyError` because the key is incorrectly set to `" hunterFileHandler"`. If you change this line to

```
keys=consoleHandler,hunterFileHandler
```

then the file should load correctly.

However, you should note that several bugs were fixed in 2.5 and 2.6, so you may be bitten by one of these (apart from the one I've mentioned). See jcollado's comment to your question.